# Pass by reference through multiple functions?

Tags: powershell, pass-by-reference

In PowerShell, it does not seem possible to pass variables by reference through multiple functions. Is there some way to do this? The below code doesn't work:

```
function f1([ref]$out){
    f2 ([ref]$out)   
}

function f2([ref]$out){
    $out.Value = "f2out"
}

$refvar = "junk"

f1 ([ref]$refvar)
Write-Host $refvar
```

Output:

```
junk
```

Comment: Since f1 is being passed a reference, then f2 should be passed only the value, which is already a reference. `f2($out)`. Otherwise, you are just referencing a reference.

Comment: Thank you, derp. I should have realized that.

Answer (score 2):

Functions `f1` and `f2` are expecting a reference as a parameter value. When the parameter value `[ref]$out` is passed into `f1`, `$out` is now a reference in that function's scope. Therefore, you only need to pass `$out` into a called function within `f1`'s scope.

```
function f1([ref]$out){
 f2($out)   
}

function f2([ref]$out){
    $out.Value = "f2out"
}

$refvar = "junk"
f1([ref]$refvar)
$refvar
# Output
f2out
```

You can see this happening within `f1` if you add some debug code.

```
function f1([ref]$out){
    $out.GetType()
    $out
}

$refvar = 'junk'
f1([ref]$refvar)

# Output

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
False    False    PSReference`1                            System.Management.Automation.PSReference

Value : junk
```